# google play display "whats new" after the description?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I can not figure out how to display the whats new content after the description, some apps have that though..

I do not want bugfixes to be the first thing that my users read..

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you want to achieve, or at least point to an app description?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.JanVeit.ArcAngel this is my app description, if you look at this on your phone or tablet, the whats new section appears above the description.

Comment: If you look at the app Catchy Basket, the whats new section is BELOW the description

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mds.catchybasket a link to that, it appears only on mobile devices though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the app downloaded, Google displays the What's New first. If you don't, then it displays the Description first. This is so what's most important can be shown first. A new user cares more about the description, a user who already has the app cares about what's new.

I just verified this, your app shows the Description first for me, an app that I made and don't have also shows Description first. All apps I've downloaded show what's new first.

There doesn't seem to be anything that can be done to change this behavior.

Comment: thank you thats very good anyway, didnt get it that its on all apps I downloaded ^^

Comment: It took me a while to figure out as well, but it makes a lot of sense now that I know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the content you are talking about is available when your are uploading a new version of an apk for an existing app in google play. Google play then provides a segment where you are supposed to describe what changes are available in this new version compared to previous version.

If you are uploading your apk for the first time, this link may not be available for you.

Comment: yes, it is not my problem, that I cant add the changes. The problem is that the changes appear at the top in the store. Some apps have it below the normal description, thats what I want.